# How to create a custom marker in google map with bubble chat background and a number on top right of image like flirt maps?

Tags: google-maps, gps, overlay, google-maps-markers

Please note that this is different from infowindow, which you can put any html code, but it is only activated when you click on the marker.
I know you can have different marker icons, but how does the shadowing (bubble chat) and the custom number appear? Like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/058/Purple/57/b2/20/mzl.cluqsjfk.320x480-75.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom overlay to use whatever HTML and CSS you want as a "marker".

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am thinking of using leaflet js, seems to have a few plugins that support this function